# Pandas: How to rename a cod's description when the same descriptions appears to different code?

Tags: python, pandas

I've tried with chat gpt but it didn't help.
I have this reproducible dataframe where the same description appears in two codes. But I need to differentiate the descriptions by adding an "X" at the end (for example). That is to say, there should be only one "gce_descri" for every "gce_cod" and only one "gce_cod" for each "gce_descri", despite the other columns (in this example, "time")

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'time': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
'gce_cod': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A1','A5','A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A1','A5'],
'gce_descri': ['description1', 'description2', 'description1', 'description3', 'description1','description2','description1', 'description2', 'description1', 'description3', 'description1','description2']})
```

The output should be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'time': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
'gce_cod': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A1','A5','A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A1','A5'],
'gce_descri': ['description1', 'description2', 'description1X', 'description3', 'description1','description2X','description1', 'description2', 'description1X', 'description3', 'description1','description2X']})
```

[image: DESIRED OUTPUT]

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I believe that is because you only change when the same `gce_descri` appears for another `gce_cod` index 4 `gce_cod` is the same as index 0 so no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I arrive at this solution after trying a while:

### First i remade your dataframe with fruits emojis to make the changes more obvious:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'time': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
'gce_cod': ['A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A1','A5','A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A1','A5'],
'gce_descri': ['', '','', '', '', '','','', '', '', '', '','']})
```

### Then this solution needs the data to be sorted

Because we will making a cummulative sum of the ocurrences of the fruits. But as this count has some conditions we will make another column with a key to group the df later.

```
df = df.sort_values(["time","gce_cod","gce_descri"])
df['key'] = df['time'].astype(str) + '_' + df['gce_descri'] + '_' + 
df['gce_cod']
```

### Then the tricky part.

The conditions of this cummulative sum as i understand are these:

1. The scope ef each sum is one time period
2. A value is counted only if:
   a) The fruit is duplicated
   b) Is in an ocurrence of different 'gce_cod'

So i made another df for the unique ocurrences of the variable 'key' that we made in the last step. Regard is a variable composed of of the three variables of our starting df. Then we cant make this cummulative sum in 'count' variable.

```
uniqueKeysDf = pd.DataFrame(dict(
key=df.key.unique(),
descri=[string[:3] for string in df.key.unique()]
))
uniqueKeysDf['count'] = uniqueKeysDf.groupby(['descri']).cumcount()+1
```

### At last we merge the df by its 'key' variable and repeat the quantity of fruits depending the 'count' value.

```
df = pd.merge(df,uniqueKeysDf[['key', 'count']],'left',on='key')
df.gce_descri =  df.apply(lambda x: x['gce_descri'] + (x['count'] - 1) * 
x['gce_descri'] if x['count'] > 1 else x['gce_descri'], axis=1)
df = df.drop(['key', 'count'], axis=1)
```

### So this is the fruit of our endeavors

```
time    gce_cod gce_descri
0   1   A1  
1   1   A1  
2   1   A2  
3   1   A2  
4   1   A3  
5   1   A4  
6   1   A5  
7   2   A1  
8   2   A1  
9   2   A2  
10  2   A3  
11  2   A4  
12  2   A5
```

Answer (score 1):

With 2 boolean masks: one for both `gce_cod/gce_descri` columns duplicates (rowwise) and one for `gce_descri` column, to further calculate *bitwise exclusive OR* `^` between them:

```
df['gce_descri'] = np.where(df.duplicated() ^ df['gce_descri'].duplicated(),
                            df['gce_descri']+'X', df['gce_descri'])
```

---

```
  gce_cod     gce_descri
0      A1   description1
1      A2   description2
2      A3  description1X
3      A4   description3
4      A1   description1
5      A5  description2X
```

Comment: Thanks! The output is correct, but the code is not referencing to the "gce_cod". So, imagine that there is another column named "month"; in that case, the repeated values of "gce_descri" for the same "gce_cod" will have an "X" at the end. The idea is that there should be only one description for each code, and only one code for each description. Let me rephrase the main question. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you find the duplicates using [pd.Dataframe.duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

Then use pd.where to replace those duplicated rows with your own values.

```
find_duplicates = df['gce_descri'].duplicated()

df['gce_descri'] = df['gce_descri'].where(~find_duplicates, df['gce_descri'] + '_X')
```

The Output

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HfAl.png)

**Note :- All duplicated values in 'gce_descri' will be changed**